# Laravel collective how to set Form::date default value based on the object value

Tags: php, laravel, laravelcollective

I have my edit route which displays an edit form view to allow me to edit details for specific member.

I have forms such as

```
{{Form::text('first_name', $member->first_name, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
```

For all Form::text it is easy to set default value as all I do is fetching first_name value from $member object.

How can I apply the same thing for my Form::date?

```
{{Form::date('dob', '\Carbon\Carbon::now()')}}
```

I have tried adding parameter similar to ::text but it does not work. Also the database value uses format of YYYY-MM-DD, whereas Form::date displays YYYY/MM/DD

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try it without the single quotes around your Carbon

```
{{Form::date('dob', \Carbon\Carbon::now())}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try do the following in the **view**

```
{{Form::date('dob', $member->date->format('Y-m-d'), ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
```

If you want you can add the date properties from your database to `protected $dates`. This will parse your dates to a carbon instance when you try to retrieve it.

**model**

```
protected $dates = ['date_column', 'deleted_at'];
```